# Apple meta viewport minimal-ui with meta apple-itunes-app promotion

Tags: html, ios, iphone, safari, meta-tags

I tried a new iOS 7.1 feature (**minimal-ui**). It works great! I combined it with **apple-itunes-app** promotion and it causes that promotion block position is 25px top. This problem is after page load. If page is loading => it is is OK.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimal-ui" />
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=__ID__, app-argument=__ARGUMENT__" />
```

[image: Minimal UI with apple-itunes-app]

Has anyone solution for this issue?

Comment: Reported in Apple Bug Reporter.

Comment: why don't you use javascript and window.onload to reposition the element?

Comment: I think I can not see that element because it is rendered by Safari..